# ASP.NET services Declaring a DataSet

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the information from my database to a gridview. I have the following but I am unsure where and how to declare the data set as this method isn't working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ConsumeDSetService
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public class MyDataSet
    {
        public static DataSet ds;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localhost.Service1 myws = new localhost.Service1();
        ds = myws.GetDataSet();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that this code doesn't compile? `ds` is a property of the class MyDataSet so you would need to reference it as `MyDataSet.ds` from the button click, which is part of the class `_Default`